# Can't list alerts in the new Azure AZ 2.0 Powershell module

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

I have deployed a multi-resource metric (new) alerts for CPU monitoring for all my VMs. currently i have two open Monitor alerts in my subscription (Status: Fired).

[image: alerts fired in portal]

Problem is, that when i try to retrive the the opend alerts from my PC via Azure AZ Module, i keep getting the same message, but without any output (although i can see the alerts in the portal):

```
WARNING: 5:01:06 PM - *** The namespace for all the model classes will change from
Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Management.Models to Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models in future releases.
WARNING: 5:01:06 PM - *** The namespace for output classes will be uniform for all classes in future releases to make
it independent of modifications in the model classes.
WARNING: [Get-AzAlertHistory] Parameter deprecation: The DetailedOutput parameter will be deprecated in a future
breaking change release.
```

I couldn't retrieve the alerts history using any of the Get-AzAlertHistory cmdlets:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-AzAlertHistory
WARNING: 5:15:08 PM - *** The namespace for all the model classes will change from
Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Management.Models to Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models in future releases.
WARNING: 5:15:08 PM - *** The namespace for output classes will be uniform for all classes in future releases to make
it independent of modifications in the model classes.
WARNING: [Get-AzAlertHistory] Parameter deprecation: The DetailedOutput parameter will be deprecated in a future
breaking change release.
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-AzAlertHistory -Caller Microsoft.Insights/alertRules
WARNING: 5:15:38 PM - *** The namespace for all the model classes will change from
Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Management.Models to Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models in future releases.
WARNING: 5:15:38 PM - *** The namespace for output classes will be uniform for all classes in future releases to make
it independent of modifications in the model classes.
WARNING: [Get-AzAlertHistory] Parameter deprecation: The DetailedOutput parameter will be deprecated in a future
breaking change release.
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-AzAlertHistory -Status Fired
WARNING: 5:16:04 PM - *** The namespace for all the model classes will change from
Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Management.Models to Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models in future releases.
WARNING: 5:16:04 PM - *** The namespace for output classes will be uniform for all classes in future releases to make
it independent of modifications in the model classes.
WARNING: [Get-AzAlertHistory] Parameter deprecation: The DetailedOutput parameter will be deprecated in a future
breaking change release.
```

Could it be that there is a problem with the current az.monitor module?

Comment: Can you try those AZ PS cmdlets in the Azure Portal cloud shell and let me know the status

Comment: Same output as my local PC

Comment: I can repro your issue, and it can work use the following code: Get-AzAlertHistory -StartTime 2019-04-20T11:00:00 -EndTime 2019-05-23T12:00:00 -DetailedOutput

Comment: Strange, i don't understand why the command isn't working for me.. i've also tried your code: Get-AzAlertHistory -StartTime 2019-04-20T11:00:00 -EndTime 2019-05-20T12:00:00 -DetailedOutput but i go the same output

Comment: Try to use a later date for EndTime? like 2019-05-21T12:00:00?

Comment: @edwio, or can you just get one of them using: Get-AzAlertHistory -ResourceId /subscriptions/your_subscription_id/resourceGroups/your_resource_group/providers/microsoft.insights/alertrules/your_alert_rule_name -StartTime 2019-04-20T11:00:00

Comment: Same Output: PS Azure:\> Get-AzAlertHistory -StartTime 2019-04-20T11:00:00 -EndTime 2019-05-21T12:00:00 -DetailedOutput
WARNING: 6:28:29 AM - *** The namespace for all the model classes will change from Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Management.Models to M
icrosoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models in future releases.
WARNING: 6:28:29 AM - *** The namespace for output classes will be uniform for all classes in future releases to make it independent of modi
fications in the model classes.

Comment: i've alst tried using Get-AzAlertHistory -ResourceId but without any luck

Comment: @edwio  It's weird :(. Can you check your local computer's date and time?

Comment: now that you mention it , when i've upgrade my PS version from v2 to v5.1 i experience the following error: Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime". But i ignore it because i didn't change the clock in my PC. which is accurate (synchronized with Microsoft)

Comment: @edwio, since it does not work both in local and cloud shell, I suggest you can open a support ticket. Follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).

Answer (score 0):

Try the new cmdlet `Get-AzAlert` which needs the module `Install-Module -Name Az.AlertsManagement`

For example: To get the alert datetime and monitor condition,

> `Get-AzAlert -TargetResourceId <resourceID> -Select "StartDateTime,MonitorCondition"`

Reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.alertsmanagement/get-azalert?view=azps-6.3.0

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.